# How to find all error messages and display them in descending order

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to sort input file from user for error messages in descending orders of occurrence.

**input_file.txt**

```
23545 debug code_to_debug
43535 error check your code
34243 error check values
32442 run program execute
24525 error check your code
```

I want to get output as

```
error check your code
error check values
```

My code currently:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileToRead"));
        Map<String, String> map=new TreeMap<String, String>();
        String line="";
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            map.put(getField(line),line);
        }
        reader.close();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("fileToWrite");
        for(String val : map.values()){
            writer.write(val);  
            writer.write('\n');
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    private static String getField(String line) {
        return line.split(" ")[0];//extract value you want to sort on
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you tried so far?

Comment: Can you use perl or ruby?  This is a 3 line program in either language.

Answer (score 0):

Change your mapping from `<String, String>` to `<Integer, String>`.  Then, use a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to compare the `Integers` from least to greatest.

It appears that your error messages are ranked by an integer value from most severe to least severe.  This should allow you to use that fact.

Comment: I don't think that would produce the output they are after... There is an "error check your code" with highest int value and second lowest int value

Comment: I'd argue (quite strongly) that becomes a matter of what you place into the map, then.  Or, have a slightly saner numbering scheme, such as those two errors *should* be equivalent.

Comment: Yes I agree, the numbering sequence appears to have no logical meaning (possibly does to OP).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a `Map<String,String>` where the key is the integer value you could have the key as the error message and then the value could hold a list of the integer values so when reading the file it would become something like and also implement a comparator in the map to order them:

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(new Comparator<String>()
    {
         @Override
         public int compare(String s1, String s2)
         {
             //Implement a compare to get the order of string you want
         }
    }
);
String line = "";
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
     String lineStr = line.split(" ")[1]; // get the message
     List<String> vals = map.get(lineStr) // get the existing list
     if( vals == null)
          vals = new ArrayList<String>(); // create a new list if there isn't one
     vals.add(getFeild(line));            // add the int value to the list

     map.put(lineStr,vals);               // add to map  
}
```

You could then sort the list into numeric order if you wanted. Also this would then require a bit more work to print out the map - but this depends on the format

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is reorder the input so all the error messages appear at the top, a very simple way to do it is like the following:

```
static String[] errorsToTop(String[] input) {
    String[] output = new String[input.length];

    int i = 0;
    for(String line : input) {
        if(line.contains("error"))
            output[i++] = line;
    }

    for(String line : input) {
        if(!line.contains("error"))
            output[i++] = line;
    }

    return output;
}
```

That just copies the array first starting with all errors messages, then will all non-error messages.

It's also possible to make those two loops a nested loop though the logic is less obvious.

```
static String[] errorsToTop(String[] input) {
    String[] output = new String[input.length];

    int i = 0;
    boolean not = false;
    do {
        for(String line : input) {
            if(line.contains("error") ^ not)
                output[i++] = line;
        }
    } while(not = !not);

    return output;
}
```

It's unclear to me whether the numbers appear in your input text file or not. If they don't, you can use `startsWith` instead of `contains`:

```
if(line.startsWith("error"))
```

You could also use `matches` with a regex like:

```
if(line.matches("^\\d+ error[\\s\\S]*"))
```

which says "starts with any integer followed by a space followed by error followed by anything or nothing".

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer has been marked I'll add 2 cents.
This code below works for exactly what you posted (and maybe nothing else), it assumes that errors have higher numbers than non errors, and that you are grabbing top N of lines based on a time slice or something.

```
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SortDesc {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NavigableMap<Integer, String> descendingMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>().descendingMap();
    descendingMap.put(23545, "debug code_to_debug");
    descendingMap.put(43535, "error check your code");
    descendingMap.put(34243, "error check values");
    descendingMap.put(32442, "run program execute");
    descendingMap.put(24525, "error check your code");

    System.out.println(descendingMap);
  }
}
```

results look like this

{43535=error check your code, 34243=error check values, 32442=run program execute, 24525=error check your code, 23545=debug code_to_debug}